# Setting QPixmap size to fill space in QGridLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been trying to display an image in a QGridLayout, and resize it according to the space available to it. However I can't seem to get the right size.

I have created a `class ImageWidget(Qwidget)`, which is what is referenced as `self` below, and an instance of which `ImageWidget0` is added to the QGridLayout `Layout` with `Layout.addWidget(ImageWidget0, 0, 0)`.

This is how I'm resizing the pixmap, and it is displaying the image in the layout  at the specified size with no problems:

```py
self.label = QLabel(self)
self.pixmap = self.pixmap.scaled(image_size[0], image_size[1], Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
self.show()
```

However different methods of assigning `image_size` are giving undesirable results. Both of the following, using the size of the widget and the size of the label respectively, produce an `image_size` of (100, 30), which is too small:

```py
image_size = (self.width(), self.height())
image_size = (self.label.width(), self.label.height())
```

So I tried to get the size of the rows and columns instead using the only methods I could find in the [QGridLayout documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html), but the following (perhaps unsuprisingly) both produce an `image_size` of (0, 0):

```py
image_size = (self.parent().layout.columnMinimumWidth(0), self.parent().layout.rowMinimumHeight(0))
image_size = (self.parentWidget().layout.columnMinimumWidth(0), self.parentWidget().layout.rowMinimumHeight(0))
```

To be clear: The layout itself is NOT CHANGING for all these different pixmap sizes. If `image_size` is manually set too large, it clips out (which is fine), but when it is too small, it just shrinks in the available space. This is what make me think the problem doesn't lie in the layout adjusting to the pixmap size.

I can post more code if required, but I was trying to keep this succinct and to the point.

Comment: By creating the QLabel as child of the widget (and not adding it to the layout) will make it completely indifferent to the layout geometry. If you want to properly resize the image based on the contents of the layout, you have to resize it overriding `resizeEvent()`. You cannot rely on widget size upon construction, at that point the layout is not activated yet, and if the widget is added to another layout it wouldn't be valid anyway.

Comment: @musicamante Ok thanks for the input. So, if I understand correctly, I should either add the QLabel to the layout directly, or resize the image after the layout has been activated? (Or both?) And if I want its size to change upon the layout being resized, I do that by overriding resizeEvent()?

Comment: The `resizeEvent()` will always be called at least once as soon as the widget is shown, so resizing the pixmap in the initialization is pointless. From your question it's not really clear how should the image be resized, but if you want it to always scale to the contents **and** the layout is static and pre-defined in the init, then you can add the label at cell 0, 0 with row and column span based on the layout row/column count; unfortunately, this will also make the layout completely ignore the spacing, so it's probably better to do it in the `resizeEvent` anyway. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @musicamante I'm clocking off for the weekend, but will pick it back up on Monday with your advice. Will also put together a minimum reproducible example if I still can't figure it out, for you or other folks who might see the question then. Thanks again!

Comment: I just remembered that you can also use stylesheets to do that. Set a *unique* object name for the container widget and use `#uniqueName { border-image: url(image.png); }`. Note that it will only work for basic QWidget instances (or widgets that support that property), if you're using a QWidget subclass you *must* override its `paintEvent()` anyway, with `opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOption()` `opt.initFrom(self)` `qp = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)` `qp.drawPrimitive(QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_Widget, opt)`. See the [QWidget stylesheet reference](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qwidget-widget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @musicamante pointed out, it is pointless using the widget size at construction as the layout has not yet been set. I got around this by adding a "load image" button, which could add the image once the layout had been created, allowing me to set the size correctly using:

```py
image_size = (self.width(), self.height())
image_size = (self.width(), self.height())
```